# Can I have four AA batteries in hand-luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage, airbaltic

I am travelling from Vilna to Stockholm with AirBaltic, in Europe. I am wondering if you can carry the batteries in the hand luggage.

Comment: I had my hand luggage separated for extra screening. The lady said I had batteries in it. I could simply not figure out where I had batteries. Then she told me the physical location in the bag and I had my battery powered mouse which totally had skipped my mind. Though she didn't take the batteries away.

Comment: @Newton So in your case, it was allowed to have those batteries. It would be nice to know how it is officially.

Comment: Yes you can, I carry rechargeable batteries (eneloops) all the time without issue. You have to make sure that if they are naked, they are carried in a case where their metal contacts are not touching; something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B017946HAQ/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2?psc=1).

Comment: Note that you are allowed but sometimes they will take them away anyway, believing they are Lithium batteries, so make sure whichever one you have are labelled NiMh,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lithium ion and lead acid batteries are the ones airlines concerned about.  The latter contain corrosive liquid.  The former can overheat and light on fire, and airlines don't want them in the cargo hold if that happens (they can react much more quickly if it happens in the passenger compartment).

The batteries you're showing are likely nickel metal hydride (or possibly nickel cadmium).  These are safe and shouldn't be a problem on any airline.